# How to select custom data from WordPress DB to android SQLite

Tags: php, android, json, wordpress, sqlite

I am developing an Android application which is needed to retrieve ***custom data*** from ***WordPress DB*** and save them to SQLite DB. From my own ***Web App***, I am receiving posts in 3 below steps:

1- The Mobile application sends request containing the required post(s) ID to the web app.

2- Web app, executes query where id is equal to requested ID.

3- Web app parses selected data to JSON format and response the JSON file back to Mobile Application.

Now, I need to receive such a data from WordPress DB, parse it to JSON file and then send the file back to mobile. The mobile application is like a product that loads latest news from online news website. Please help me to solve this problem. I am really in need of it.

Thanks.

Comment: There are alot of REST or Json API plugins available, using those you should be able to generate your json formatted posts. When you want to save in sqlite, you need to build a json parser, alot of examples are found on the internet. Saving the parsed json to sqlite shouldnt be much of a problem, as documentation and tutorials are available aswell

Comment: @imatwar Thank u for invaluable answer. But the mobile application is like a product. Each mobile may send different request with different ID. The mobile must to select needed posts from WordPress Database which for each mobile might be different ID. The plugins just select and shows them in the WordPress dashboard but I need them in mobile app.

Comment: @ImAtWar I found the way to use the JSON API but the problem is here that I need the post from for example 30 to last post. Searching for it over the internet but couldn't find appropriate answer. :)